# graphql вопрос точки

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Хочу изучить graphql.

Сервер должен быть не стандартный rest api? к примеру router.get('/', [],funk)?  Или я устанавливаю graphql и у меня автоматически над сервером возникает обоолочка с точкой graphql.